# c++ constructor question

Tags: c++, constructor

I am still confused with the CTORs:

**Question 1:**
why line 15 call `A:A(int)` instead of `A:A(double&)`?

**Question 2:**
why line 18 did not call `A:A(B&)`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B{};

class A{
public:
   A(int )    {cout<<"A::A(int)"<<endl;}
   A(double&){cout<<"A::A(double&)"<<endl;} // it will work if it is A(double), without the &
   A(B&){cout<<"A::A(B&)"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
/*line 15*/   A obj((double)2.1);  // this will call A(int), why?
   B obj2;
   A obj3(obj2);
/*line 18*/   A obj4(B);          // this did not trigger any output why?
}
```

Comment: Most reasonable compilers would at least print out a warning about a double-to-int conversion.

Comment: @Kerrek: [Yes. Yes, it does.](http://codepad.org/hvNeJZUZ) (Though note the warning, and you will have to forgive codepad's `-Werror`.)

Comment: @Tomalak:Hah, I didn't know you can omit the parentheses for the default constructor. You can even say `A x(int);`... something new every day:-)

Comment: @Kerrek: Huh? You _have_ to omit parentheses for the default constructor, otherwise you're declaring a function. Which is also what you're doing in `A x(int);`.

Comment: @Tomalak: You can also write `A x(int());`...

Comment: @Kerrek: [And that's still a function declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @TomalaK: I fell for that one again :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Line 15:** `A(double&)` can only take lvalues, i.e. variables that can be assigned to. `(double)2.1` is an rvalue. Use `A(const double&)` if you need to accept rvalues as reference too.

**Line 18:** `B` is a type, not a value. `A obj4(B);` only declares a function with name `obj4` taking a `B` and returning an `A`.

Comment: Thanks all for the fast response. I changed line 18 to be A obj4(B()), it is still not working. I then changed it to be A obj4((B())), then it works. Is A obj4(B()) still a function?

Comment: @John: Yes. It is a function called `obj4` that takes a function with no name that takes nothing and returns a `B`, and returns an `A`. :) [Read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Now I start to regret becoming a programmer :)

Comment: @John: Just wait until you get to templates! For what it's worth, you absorbed all these responses very quickly and from what I can tell, you understood them. So... good job!

Answer (score 3):

### Line 15

Your reference constructors accept only references to non-`const` objects.

That is, you wrote:

```
A(int)     { cout<<"A::A(int)"<<endl; }
A(double&) { cout<<"A::A(double&)"<<endl; }
A(B&)      { cout<<"A::A(B&)"<<endl; }
```

instead of:

```
A(int)           { cout<<"A::A(int)"<<endl; }
A(double const&) { cout<<"A::A(double const&)"<<endl; }
A(B const&)      { cout<<"A::A(B const&)"<<endl; }
```

The problem with this is that, in `A obj((double)2.1)`, you invoked the constructors with *temporary objects* (in this case, the double literal `2.1` (that cast to `double` is pointless), and temporary objects may not bind to references that are not references to `const`.

So the `A(double&)` constructor cannot be called; the only one left that might match is `A(int)`, and the required conversion is performed on your data (`2.1` → `2`) to make this happen. (Your compiler [will normally warn you](http://codepad.org/hvNeJZUZ) that this occurring.)

So, use the form of constructor that accepts reference to `const`.

---

### Line 18

As for your `A obj4(B)`, `B` is a type so you're declaring a function named `obj4` that takes an (unnamed) `B` and returns an `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `&` means it is a reference type and on line 15 you pass a value, not a reference.

Comment: You never "pass" a reference.

Comment: How would you go about passing a reference? I would be very interested :)

Comment: @Tomalak, Maybe I used the wrong words, but it does expect a reference and not a value. So, is my answer wrong?

Comment: @nightcracker, it's just a "phrase" commonly used where I mostly spend my days.. I mean that it expects a reference and he is "passing" hence "using"/"sending" or whatever word you want for it.

Comment: @Filip: I think you've confused terminology. You only ever pass "values" into functions; some functions copy them into new objects, others work with the existing objects ("accept by reference") and others just don't match at all... like this one. That's because you cannot _bind_ the temporary/rvalue literal `2.1` to a reference parameter. But there is no way that you can fix that by "passing a reference" from the callsite.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: The problem is not the reference. Anything can be a reference. The problem is one of `const`-ness.

Comment: @Tomalak, yeah well that's what I mean, maybe I used the wrong wording here. What I mean is that he is not "sending" or whatever I should call it a reference type...

Comment: If my answer is wrong ( not the wording ) i can happily remove it, I just want to know if it's the wording or the answer thats wrong.

Comment: @nightcracker: Not anything. A reference to a `double` literal can't be a reference (it cannot exist).

Comment: @Filip: It's better to talk from the function's perspective. He's not _accepting_ a reference into that function. "Sending" things to the function doesn't really have as much weight, when you bring implicit conversions and reference binding into it, because you never do this stuff in code at the callsite.

Comment: @nightcracker: Er, `s/A reference to a/A non-const, non-rvalue reference to a double literal/;` :P

Comment: Of course, but did you read my complete comment you responded to? _" The problem is not the reference. Anything can be a reference. The problem is one of const-ness."_ I already said that :P

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to know if the answer was incorrect or if you guys hung up on my wording. :) I'll delete it as it doesn't add any value to the question.

Comment: @nightcracker: Yes, and "anything can be a reference" is incorrect. Something that's not in a `const` context can't!

Comment: @Filip: I made a dummy edit so I can remove my downvote. You're right, the answer itself is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Line 15, the double is an rvalue (a temporary) and cannot convert to a non-const reference. For Line 18, the most likely explanation is that your compiler simply optimized out the constructor call.

Comment: If the compiler optimized it out then he must file a bug because the compiler is not allowed to optimize anything out that puts out output. I think KennyTM nailed it about line 18.

Comment: @Nightcracker: Constructors have special leeway in this regard.

Comment: @DeadMG: Nonsense. Line 18 doesn't even _contain_ a constructor call.

Comment: @nightcracker: Unfortunately, though, constructors _do_ have special semantics and can be optimised out even when they have side effects. It's pretty rubbish.